# Can it be possible to add custom wrap widget menu in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

On VScode, Flutter project selected widget tag and with "Ctrl + ." shortcut occur opening menu that includes such as "wrap this with Container". I wonder this is possible. These menu options enrich with new items such as wrap this with Stack etc.

Answer (score 1):

The options on that menu are part of the flutter vscode extension. You can't take away or add items to that menu, but if you want to do something like wrap a widget in a stack, you can wrap the widget in a column or row, then change `Column` or `Row` to `Stack`.

Comment: Thank you. your advise helps to me

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

This feature was [requested for VS Code](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1890), but looks like it was closed after a generic "Wrap with Builder" assist was added.